# How do I DECLARE or SET multiple values in SQL?

Tags: sql

**Goal:** Set multiple values in the DECLARE statement to use in the WHERE statement.

**Issue:** Cannot successfully add multiple values in the SET statement.

**Example of what I’m trying to complete:**

```
DECLARE @Beverage as varchar(1000)
SET @Beverage = (‘Water’, ‘Soda’, ‘Wine’, ‘Beer’)

SELECT Beverage
FROM ExampleServer
WHERE Beverage in (@Beverage)
```

**Example of what currently executes correctly:**

```
DECLARE @Beverage as varchar(1000)
SET @Beverage = (‘Water’)

SELECT Beverage
FROM ExampleServer
WHERE Beverage in (@Beverage)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a Table-Valued Variable instead?

Comment: which version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable as a temporary table :

```
declare @myList table (Beverage varchar(255) )
```

populate it with values :

```
insert into @myList values ("Water"), ("Soda"), ("Wine"), ("Beer")
```

Then you can use either the in statement :

```
select Beverage from ExampleServer 
where Beverage in (select Beverage from @myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

A variable can hold a *single scalar value*, you can't assign multiple values.

If you wish to hard-code a list of values like in your question you can use a *values* table constructor; you can then select from your table and check with an *exists* correlation:

```
with b as (
  select beverage from (values ('Water'), ('Soda'), ('Wine'), ('Beer'))b(beverage)
)
select t.Beverage
from ExampleServer t
where exists (
  select * from b
  where b.beverage = t.beverage
);
```

The above is assuming *SQL Server*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the " EXEC (@sqlString) ". This will help you to build your SQL queries dynamically and then execute them with the command EXEC as if they are Stored procedure

```
DECLARE @BEVERAGE VARCHAR(200),@SQLstring VARCHAR(1000)

SET @BEVERAGE ='('+CHAR(39)+'Water'+CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39)+'Soda'+CHAR(39)+
              ','+CHAR(39)+'Wine'+CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39)+'Beer'+CHAR(39)+')'
SET @SQLstring = 'SELECT Beverage FROM ExampleServer WHERE Beverage IN 
                 '+@BEVERAGE

--SELECT @SQLstring
EXEC (@SQLstring)
```

- I'm using the "CHAR(39)" instead of " ' " for avoid some troubles with the string declaration